# How to build private chatroom with PHP+Mysql and websocket?

Tags: php, mysql, websocket, chat

I am interested learning websocket as chat application. I have gone through PHP websocket https://github.com/Flynsarmy/PHPWebSocket-Chat. This app is running very nice as mentioned by many.

After much struggle I ultimately learned apache server and websocket are completely different entities. I cannot use PHP session, cookies in websocket. I tried even angularjs and ngStorage to user session to be used in websocket. In nutsheel I failed to create chat application in which one user can chat privately with other in a particular tab with GET request.

My TARGET: I want chat application based on above websocket application with user login system with PHP+Mysql. And when one user clicks on another to chat privately it will redirect me to another tab. And that particular tab is private chatroom between two users.

I would appreciate possible way to make chat application like FB and gmail. Where one user clicks on anyusers who is online can chat privately let say in new tab.

REQUEST: Please consider that I am just new to websocket.

Comment: This question is WAY too broad.  If you have a specific question, such as about PHP sessions, cookies, etc., (which you CAN use with WebSockets, and it has very recently been described how to use them) then ask those specific questions... but asking how to build a chat application is far, far, far beyond the scope of questions on this site.

Comment: And, I'll say it again, as I said on your previous questions: That Flynsarmy server is unsafe.  It is written for an old version of WebSockets (version 7) and has a major security flaw.  Use a server that implements the current RFC standard, version 13.